# Cannot overwrite `Kitten` model once compiled

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've run into an issue with the Mongoose [Getting Started](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) guide.

I have MongoDB running and everything is working perfectly until I add the last line:

```
Kitten.find({ name: /^Fluff/ }, callback)
```

When I `node server.js` I get this error:

> OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `Kitten` model once compiled.

Here's the [full error](https://gist.github.com/ryanburnett/b4597367acefb58ae9ad) and my [server.js](https://gist.github.com/ryanburnett/1b1d7e46a64666358b77).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. I'm running node 10.26, npm 1.4.13, express 4.4.3 & mongoose 3.8.12 on OS X 10.9.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because `callback` in `Kitten.find({ name: /^Fluff/ }, callback)` calls `var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);` again. Change

```
Kitten.find({ name: /^Fluff/ }, callback)
```

to something like:

```
Kitten.find({ name: /^Fluff/ }, function(err, kittens) {

});
```

It doesn't make sense to call the `callback` function again.

Comment: That works - thank you! Just a note that I needed to change the ending `}};` to `});`

Answer (score 1):

I thought this could be useful to someone else who tries it...

I started looking into mongoose and tried [Getting Started](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) guide. I don't see the above error happening where it was reported. However, I did see it intermittently. If it happens, follow #3 below. Here are my observations:

***Issue#1.*** If I copy paste the whole code I see an issue with "I don't have a name" as the single quote in don't is not escaped.

***Solution#1.*** I tried to escape with \ and \\ but it didn't work. Google search didn't help. After some research I found that it is forgiving for single quotes outside the function. But, inside the function it won't work. So, I defined a variable outside the function. Probably better to define strings in a separate document for localization anyways. Above all, it works. :)

***Issue#2.*** I see the issue at
fluffy.speak();
TypeError: fluffy.speak is not a function
Here since the first 'mongoose.model(...)' doesn't have this method, adding it later and re-running 'mongoose.model(...)' will not help.

***Solution#2.*** Comment the first 'mongoose.model(...)'

***Issue#3.*** When I copy paste the code from the web site, it is causing weird errors.

***Solution#3.*** Just deleted all the tabs and empty spaces at the end of lines in a Notepad++. That took care of it.

Here is the code that worked for me (Needless to say, if it doesn't work, please copy paste first in notepad):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection.error:'));
db.once('open', function(callback) {
//yay!
});

var kittySchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: String
});
//var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);

//var silence = new Kitten({ name: 'Silence' });
//console.log(silence.name);
//console.log(silence);

var noname = "I don't have a name";

kittySchema.methods.speak = function () {
var greeting = this.name
? "Meow name is " + this.name
: noname;
console.log(greeting);
}
var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);

var fluffy = new Kitten({ name : 'fluffy' });
fluffy.speak();
```